# Adobe AIR fullscreen executable performance

Tags: air, fullscreen, executable

If this is the improper forum, please advise. Just trying to get an answer.

For a recent project I am running a full screen (desktop) executable created with Adobe AIR.

After a lot of testing what I've discovered is that the full screen executable ALWAYS performs better with buttery smooth tweens when the Flash IDE is open. If I close the IDE, relaunch the executable, there is noticeable stutter.

This makes no sense but have repeated several times with same results. Can anyone suggest a reason why and a possible solution in lieu of having to launch the IDE as well?

Comment: Are you building in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: AFAIK debug mode or release mode only apply when you are targeting mobile, there is a 'deployment' tab missing when publishing to the desktop.

Comment: Both modes exist in desktop. Flash Pro's debug set is incredibly limited, though, so it may not make it apparent that you can.